# Dropzone is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am quite new at JavaScript and this is driving me crazy.

I want to use Dropzone.js so I downloaded the file dropzone.js from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js) and included it in my view like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo JS_DIRECTORY; ?>/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Then I created the form like that:

```
<form action="http://localhost/project/uploadTest/upload" class="dropzone">
</form>
```

And it works fine. It points it to php function and I handle upload on server site.

The problem is when I want to access the dropzone object in JS to configure it.
When I do

```
// "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code might run too soon. Wrap it in:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // access Dropzone here
};
```

or, better (runs sooner than above code):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // access Dropzone here
});
```

or, if you use `jQuery`:

```
$(function() {
    // access Dropzone here
});
```

Comment: I've been using dropzone in my project for a couple years now without using $(function() {}); but today I encountered this error and $(function() {}); is not helping at all.. I wonder why?

Comment: There can be many reasons. Check (1) order of the `<script src>` tags, (2) whether they use `async` and/or `defer` attribute, (3) place of the inline script(s), (4) whether it works when using `window.onload`. If you cannot make it work, I suggest to ask a new question providing all the necessary details allowing to reproduce the issue.

Comment: only `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()` worked for me, otherwise it was saying that Dropzone is already attached

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

Your HTML file:

```
<form action="your url" class="dropzone" id="dropzone-form">
</form>
```

Your JS file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // dropzoneFormis the configuration for the element that has an id attribute
    // with the value dropzone-form (or dropzoneForm)
    //initialize the dropzone;
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            autoProcessQueue: 'your value',
            acceptedFiles: 'your value',
            maxFilesize: 'your value',
            ....and so on.
            init: function() {
               myDropzone = this;

               this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                   //todo...something...
               }
               //catch other events here...
            }
    };
};
```